# How insert data in Oracle SQL (date) with different format

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I change my date column format on dd-mon-yyyy? I dont want it to be stored as typical 18/03/28 (EU here)

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
      employee_id NUMBER(5),
      first_name VARCHAR2(100),
      last_name VARCHAR2(100),
      salary NUMBER(8),
      department_id NUMBER(5),
      hire_date date, 
      CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (employee_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_emp_dept FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES department(department_id)
    );
```

It would be easier to change select view by simply

```
select to_char(hire_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') from employee;
```

but I have to insert 150 rows with dd-mon-yyyy (28-MAR-2018)

Comment: Date values do not have a format. Any format you see is applied by the SQL client you are using.

Answer (score 4):

A date is stored as a value without formatting.  You can convert a formatted text to `date` using [`to_date`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php), and back using [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm).

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(YourColumn, 'DD/MON/YYYY')
FROM   YourTable

INSERT INTO YourTable
       (..., YourColumn, ...)
VALUES (..., TO_DATE('31/JAN/2017', 'DD/MON/YYYY'), ...);
```

Alternatively, you can [change your session's default date format](http://dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_change_the_default_data_format.htm):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MON/YYYY';
```

Comment: Thank you, change of sessions default date format is a great concept, but when I try insert new row I get an error                                       ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: @Dasedrot: Is your installation set to the same language as you are inserting? For French, you'd use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH'; `

Comment: @Dasedrot: When using literals for dates, you should better not use string literals that you convert to date (like in `TO_DATE('31/JAN/2017', 'DD/MON/YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')`, but date literals right away (like `DATE '2017-01-31'`).

Comment: @Andomar: When converting strings that contain month names, always specify the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE as shown in my comment above in order to be independent from session settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/RR';

create table test_table2 (datecol date);
insert into test_table2 select '18/03/28' from dual;

select * from test_table2;
```